# 'InstrumentedList' object has no attribute 'Location' when traversing relationship

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have 3 tables that I'm having trouble traversing. These consist of a CAR table, a LOCATION table, and a CARLOCATION table. Car holds car data, location holds location data, and the carlocation table sits in the middle, and links a car to its current location.

Using Flask and SQLAlchemy, I want the user to be able to search a car by ID, which links to the CarLocation table with a relationship, and the CarLocation table links to the Location table via a relationship as well. So Car -> CarLocation -> Location

However, when I'm calling Car.CarLocation.Location.Name, I'm getting an error saying:

**File "D:\Documents\GitHub\car_share\karshare\views.py", line 370, in searchcar 
CurrentLocation = SearchedCar.CarLocations.Location.Name**

**AttributeError: 'InstrumentedList' object has no attribute 'Location'**

Anybody who could assist me would be a lifesaver!

My models.py looks like below:

```
class Car(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Car'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'KarShare'}

    CarID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, server_default=db.text(
            "nextval('\"KarShare\".\"Car_CarID_seq\"'::regclass)"))
    Make = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    Model = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    Year = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    Odometer = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    CarType = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    NumSeats = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    FuelType = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    CostPerHour = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    TransmissionType = db.Column(db.String(9), nullable=False)
    Registration = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)


class CarLocations(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'CarLocations'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'KarShare'}

    CarID = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('KarShare.Car.CarID'), primary_key=True,
                      nullable=False)
    CurrentLocationID = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('KarShare.Location.LocationID'),
                                  nullable=True)
    Location = db.relationship("Location", backref="CarLocations",
                               lazy=True)
    Car = db.relationship("Car", backref="CarLocations",lazy=True)


class Location(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Location'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'KarShare'}

    LocationID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, server_default=db.text(
            "nextval('\"KarShare\".\"Location_LocationID_seq\"'::regclass)"))
    Name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    StreetAddress = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    City = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, nullable=False)
    State = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, nullable=False)
    Longitude = db.Column(db.Numeric(precision=9, scale=6), nullable=False)
    Latitude = db.Column(db.Numeric(precision=8, scale=6), nullable=False)
    CarSpaces = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
```

And the simple code causing the error:

```
     SearchedCar = Car.query.filter_by(CarID=form.search.data).first()
     Make = SearchedCar.Make
     Model = SearchedCar.Model
     Year = SearchedCar.Year
     Odometer = SearchedCar.Odometer
     CarType = SearchedCar.CarType
     NumSeats = SearchedCar.NumSeats
     FuelType = SearchedCar.FuelType
     CostPerHour = SearchedCar.CostPerHour
     TransmissionType = SearchedCar.TransmissionType
     CurrentLocation = SearchedCar.CarLocations.Location.Name
     Registration = SearchedCar.Registration
```

Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 0):

`Car` has a list of `CarLocation` via relationship:

```
- CurrentLocation = SearchedCar.CarLocations.Location.Name
+ if SearchedCar.CarLocations:
+     CurrentLocation = SearchedCar.CarLocations[0].Location.Name
```

Comment: Ah, even if there is only one result, it's returned as a list?

Comment: @Freddyg103 if you're sure that there is exactly one result, then add `uselist=False` and you don't need to call it via list index